# electron shell jumping in Iron?

Tags: condensed-matter, physical-chemistry

I understand a "little" about electron shell jumping, I was wondering about "Iron", If iron was heated to a gas, perhaps held in a vacuum maybe even under pressure, would the added energy make the electrons jump shells/orbitals?
I know Iron's electron sequence is 2,8,14,2 but was wondering if there was any way to change the sequence to 2,8,8,8 converting it to some kind of "noble element"?

Answer (score 1):

The electron configuration of iron ($Z=26$), at least using a rather outdated notation is: 
$$K=2, L=8, M=14, N=2.$$

Your question is '*how can we rearrange this to obtain* $K=2, L=8, M=8, N=8$?' because you believe that's the electron configuration of some noble gas (a Main Group VIII element).

There are two things fundamentally wrong with your reasoning.

Firstly, even when heated to a gas, the thermal energy input to move 6 of the $M$ electrons to the $N$ shell is far insufficient to achieve that. Heating up elements can only cause the *most outer electrons* (the $N$ shell in the case if iron) to 'jump' shells. $M$ and deeper shell electrons are far too tightly bound to the nucleus to be excitable by thermal means.

Secondly, there is no noble gas with the electron configuration $K=2, L=8, M=8, N=8$. With 4 shells that would be a Period 4 element and the **actual** Period 4, Main Group VIII element is [Krypton](http://www.ptable.com/), $Z=36$. The electron configuration of krypton however is $K=2, L=8, M=18, N=8$.

Comment: I realize there is no noble gas with the electron configuration K=2,L=8,M=8,N=8. but still wondered if it was even theoretically possible to move 6 M electrons to valence shell?

Comment: @MarkEmery: certainly not by heating alone, as explained in the first part: thermal excitation energy would be far too low to achieve that. Now lets assume it could be achieved by some other means. Such an Fe atom would be in a highly excited state, much removed from the eigenenergies of the ground state of Fe. It would immediately start reverting back to the ground state by a series of photon emissions.

Comment: Thanks, I only ask this question because I attempted to make a extended periodic table using electron sequences(before I had internet), at the time I only knew a few elements electron sequences, but followed what I thought at the time was the sequence, it was only a couple of years later that i found all the electron sequences online, and realized my mistakes, which all tended to be in the last two shells, iron was one, I had 2,8,8,8 instead of 2,8,14,2, also I had palladium as 2,8,18,17,1 instead of 2,8,18,18 this was because I was following what I thought was the sequence.

Comment: my extended periodic tables can be found here to explain what I mean, ignore the text, it was just my thoughts at the time,  http://alpha-omega-sunshaker.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/new-extended-periodic-tableelectron.html